# How to use a DPI aware value in a property of a component?

Tags: delphi, properties

I'm developing a text editor component with a popup window. The width of popup window should be set while designtime inside a properties editor for my component.

How can I apply the setted width to the screen resolution?

If I enter a value for `Width`, Delphi stores the value inside the .dfm file. Also there are stored a `PixelsPerInch` value. If I place a Width = 96 while I'm using a Windows DPI setting of 100%, inside the .dfm will be stored:

```
PixelsPerInch = 96
Width = 96
```

If I change my Windows DPI setting right now to 150% and reopen this project in Delphi, the properties editor shows me 148 for the width.

I would like to have this too for my value:

```
published
  property PopupWidth: Integer read FPopupWidth write FPopupWidth;
```

... but Delphi does not apply the PixelsPerInch handling for my value.

Why not? And how can I implement this?

[image]

Comment: - *"Why not?"* - Because the compiler cannot read your mind. - *".. how .."* - I think you should see code in TCustomForm.ReadState.  This may also be relevant: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Considerations_When_Dynamically_Resizing_Forms_and_Controls

Comment: It also doesn't scale other integer values that aren't pixel counts. Should it scale those?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, it should scale - that's what I want. How can I tell Delphi to scale a property?

Comment: You want it to automatically DPI scale all integer properties?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, one property only.

Comment: I suppose I'm echoing Sertac. Why are you asking why this doesn't happen automatically? You could not really expect that. In my view though, you don't want the property to be scaled that way. Just scale it at runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I would like to have the same behaviour like given for the Left, Top, Width and Height properties too. I though there would be any trick to get it. Maybe something around TCustomForm.ReadState...

Comment: You can use the same techniques as the VCL, but it is just much simpler to do it the way I said. What do you gain by doing it your way.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find your solution - I see questions from you only. Right now, I think there must any way to define properties to be scaled by the `PixelsPerInch` property of `TCustomForm`...

Comment: You have the source to the VCL right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ... and again you gave me the answer, I looked for. Thanks a lot! (Yes, I use VCL)

Comment: My point was more that you could have worked this out by reading the VCL source. That's how I did it. Obviously it's easier if you are familiar with it, but trying to work this out yourself is how you will gain that familiarity. That's all I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scaling mechanism is handled by explicit code in the VCL. The framework provides the virtual `ChangeScale` method of `TControl` to allow your controls to participate.

You would override `ChangeScale` for your control and implement it like this:

```
procedure TMyControl.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer);
begin
  if sfWidth in ScalingFlags then
    PopupWidth := MulDiv(PopupWidth, M, D);
  inherited;
end;
```